# MariaDB CSV output limitations

Tags: mysql, csv, mariadb, export-to-csv

I have some data in a MariaDB 10.2 database that I'm trying to do the following to:

1. Compose a JSON document using nested `JSON_SET` calls
2. Export a list of query results into a CSV file for use later on in another tool.

These JSON documents can vary in size, depending on what the field values are, but in general, it looks like they're in the range of 250-400 characters long. The issue I am running into is that if the JSON documents are getting truncated to 278 characters (often resulting in malformed JSON that cannot be used).

Is there a configuration or query parameter that I can use to configure this? I tried Googling for it earlier, but so far I've been unable to find anything.

Would appreciate any help!

As an example, the query looks like:

```
SELECT field_1, JSON_SET(JSON_SET('{"foo":{}}', '$.foo.bar', field_2), '$.foo.baz', field_3)
FROM test
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/test.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: Note that `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` can only be used to create a new file, it cannot be used to append to a file. In case you are always creating a new file, it might be a good idea to report this as a bug if it is easily reproducible.

Comment: What's truncating the JSON?